# bike seat or bike saddle

Tags: word-usage, differences

Coming from German, I have always said “bike saddle”. But later a friend from Philadelphia told me that the common word is “bike seat”, and I would not necessarily understood if I say saddle. Some online research indicates that in fact both are in use.

So I wonder: is there a difference in connotation, in regional use or in who uses it (enthusiastic cyclists vs. non-cyclists)?

Comment: It depend on how tight you wear your bike shorts.  There's a school of riders (in really tight shorts) who say "saddle" and a different group who say "seat".  The same with several other bike terms.  There is a physical difference in seats/saddles that drives this to a minor degree -- some are padded "seats" and others are sling-like leather "saddles".

Comment: I'll note that the [Bicycles SE site](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/) is available for bike-related questions.

Comment: The answers so far seem to indicate different use by different groups. Maybe it is partly a UK vs. US thing?

Comment: It may be partly UK/US, but there are several different cultures "within" the cycling communities of both countries, and there is as much difference there.

Answer (score 1):

Among people who ride bikes in the UK, even if they wouldn't call themselves cyclists, *saddle* appears to predominate. The word would be universally understood, with the only possible confusion being if you said you were a bit saddle sore after to much riding at the weekend and your hearer didn't know whether you meant a bike or a horse.

A lot of related components include the word *seat* (*seatpost* or very rarely *saddlepost*, always *seatstay*). Many accessories always (*saddlebag*) or usually (*saddle cover*) refer to *saddle* rather than *seat*).

*Bike seat* is also used to mean a seat for carrying a child on a bike, but *saddle* isn't.

Answer (score 0):

The pro riders tend to saddle.  Recreational users tend to seat.

[image: seat v saddle][wiki: saddles and seats](https://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/Bicycle+saddle)

They are very very close to being the same in general ... but some purists and pro may disagree.  For more read:

Answer (score 0):

Speaking only of my experience in the United States, I would agree that most people would not understand the term "bike saddle" because most are not "cyclists". In fact, I don't think I have ever heard the term used -- but then again I'm not a cyclist.

FYI - This site devoted to vintage Schwinn bikes addresses the history of "saddles" vs. "seats".  https://bikehistory.org/parts/seats.html